# Why does function template work with int[] but not with char[] arrays in D?

Tags: d

Let's say we have a simple D function template that returns the length of an array:

```
size_t len(T)(T[] arr) {
    return arr.length;
}
```

And we have two arrays:

```
int[] arr0 = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8];
char[] arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
```

Now, I also need a function template that will pretty-print the input and the result of the above `len` function template.

```
void writeResult(T)(T[] param, T result) {
    import std.stdio;
    import std.format;
    writeln(format("%s --> %s", param, result));
}
```

Now let's test `len` with our two arrays.

```
writeResult(arr0, len(arr0)); // [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8] --> 6
writeResult(arr1, len(arr1)); // writeResult cannot deduce function from argument types !()(char[], uint), candidates are:
test.d(4): writeResult(T)(T[] param, T result)
```

We have return type `size_t` for both cases but with `int[]` array it works and with `char[]` array it doesn't. What is the reason for such behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing to notice there are the arguments to your function are both of basically the same type: `T[]` and `T`.

Replace the T placeholder across the *whole* signature: `int[], int` works for your array and length... but with char, `char[], char`, now you have the problem: `len` returns `size_t` (aka `uint` on 32 bit which is why you see that in the error message), which is not the same as `char`.

I'd probably just make the second parameter `size_t` directly instead of `T`, or pass some other thing to it.

Just remember those placeholders in the function definition are always going to be the same every time they are mentioned in a particular call.

Comment: ah. that's because `T` cannot be deduced as `int` and `char` in a single template, right? I thought `T` can be `char[]` for one param and `size_t` for another.

Comment: Nope, each compile time param can have only one value. If you wanted two different things, do like `void foo(T, R)(T one, R, another){}`

Comment: i miswrote that last comment it should be `(T one, R another)`. prolly obvious but still

Answer (score 0):

It is easy your code is wrong a does not make sense. End error code is right. So I do not see any issue here.

Here is fixed code:

https://run.dlang.io/is/IitSmF

```d
size_t len(T)(T[] arr) {
    return arr.length;
}

int[] arr0 = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8];
char[] arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

void writeResult(T)(T[] param, size_t result) {
    import std.stdio;
    import std.format;
    writeln(format("%s --> %s", param, result));
}

void main()
{
    writeResult(arr0, len(arr0));
    writeResult(arr1, len(arr1));
}
```

UPDATE:

I post it too eraly (without explanation), but Adam's answer is perfect, so there is no reason to repeat it